# How to get the granted authorities/roles from custom OIDC claim using spring oidc/oauth2 (AWS cognito)

Tags: spring, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

OK so I have a basic oauth2/oidc configuration in spring/spring boot.  The authentication stuff all seems to be working reliably with minimal configuration until I attempt to access the roles.  When I look at my granted authorities of my logged in user, I only see "OIDC_USER" as my only role.  Now I know there is another claim/attribute on my id token ("cognito:groups") that contains a list of ROLES that I would like to simply trust.  I know using openid/oauth2 MUST have a common config for how to create a GrantedAuthorityMapper but I cannot for the life of me figure out what it must be.  All the googling in the world keeps bringing me deeper into coding my own JWT and oauth classes which kinda defeats the purpose of the framework.  Here are all the keys in my props file:
`
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-id=xxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-secret=123xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.redirect-uri=${app.url}/login/oauth2/code/cognito
#spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.redirect-uri=${app.url}/dashboard
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-name=myclient

#spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.scope=openid+email+profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.user-name-attribute=email
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.jwk-set-uri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aaaaaaa/.well-known/jwks.json

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.authorization-uri=https://bbbbbbbbbb.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.token-uri=https://bbbbbbbbb.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
`

Here is a the id token:

`{ "claims": { "at_hash": "111111aaaaaabbbbbbbccccc", "sub": "5a8417c7-7875-4ac5-9d7f-b0ffd1b3490f", "cognito:groups": [ "USER", "DEVELOPER", "ADMIN", "CLIENT" ], "birthdate": "01/01/1901", "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_abc123", "updated_at": { "seconds": 1675049091, "nanos": 0 }, "auth_time": { "seconds": 1679280866, "nanos": 0 }, "nickname": "First", "exp": { "seconds": 1679367266, "nanos": 0 }, "iat": { "seconds": 1679280866, "nanos": 0 }, "jti": "4f53349b-0e78-4c84-ac21-dd69ad3c9ea4", "email": "myuser@email.com", "email_verified": true, "address": { "formatted": "123 N Main St" }, "profile": "firstName", "phone_number_verified": true, "cognito:username": "myuser", "given_name": "First", "nonce": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "picture": "https://vectorified.com/images/generic-avatar-icon-24.png", "origin_jti": "8ae68e89-19b2-47a3-a2cb-34fb513ce9d0", "aud": [ "1111aaaabbb" ], "token_use": "id", "name": "First Last", "phone_number": "+11112221234", "family_name": "Last" }, "tokenValue": "xxx...", "issuedAt": { "seconds": 1679280866, "nanos": 0 }, "expiresAt": { "seconds": 1679367266, "nanos": 0 } }`

What is the right way to simply inject Either a custom claim (attribute) name to be my roles/granted authorities?  Shouldn't there be a property like spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.granted-authority-clame-name=cognito:groups
?

Why would this simple config devolve into 10 new classes and reconfiguring the security Filter chain manually?  This seems like a horrible oversight in OIDC/oauth2 spring plugin if I have to build the entire thing from @Bean references of the entire JWT infrastructure.  So far I have tried creating beans for each of the following:
`Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>  JWTProcessor<SecurityContext>  JwtAuthenticationConverter JwtDecoder` 
None of the above beans seems to make any difference without manually configuring the security  filter chain, which makes me feel like I am goin backwards

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
-Matt

so far I tried implementing all of JWT related beans expecting to have a bean of type
GrantedAuthorityMapper or JwtAuthenticationConverter.  Neither of which seem to affect the OIDC config that I already have tested and working

I tired searching for granted authority spring properties to set the ROLE field from the ID token on the spring config.

I even tried configuring the security filter chain by hand but that seems to be completely break the oauth/oidc flow.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing about JWTs, so I guess you are trying to configure a resource server.

All you have to do to provide your own roles mapping is to provide a Converter from Jwt to JwtAuthenticationToken. This is called only if the JWT access token (not ID token) validation is successful:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...);
```

But yes, you'll have to write this converter and configure it in a `SecurityFilterChain` defined by yourself, unless you use one of "my" starters wich are thin wrappers around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and allow to configure authorities mapping (as well as CORS configuration and a few other things) from application properties.

Refer to this tutorials I wrote for doing what you want with either my starters (no java conf) or Spring Boot official one (quite some Java conf): https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: At the risk of sounding ungrateful (which I definitely am not!),  This answer did not really help me as much as I would like.  I looked at https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/SecurityConfig.java but it is diffcult to tell what parts I need.  I can't possibly need all 263 lines right?

Comment: First, you are obviously talking about the solution without my starters (which is 0 Java line long for your use case)

Comment: Second, the solution in this tutorial aims at satisfying multi-tenancy (accept identities from several trusted OIDC Providers). It works with a single authorization server, but you can do simpler if you'll ever have only one Cognito instance as OP: configure just the `jwtAuthenticationConverter` on the `resourceServer` configuration. This saves the AuthenticationManagerResolver definition.

Comment: Also, if always mapping authorities from just `cognito:groups`, you can write a simpler authorities converter than the one exposed there (which maps from any claims based on configuration properties). With a fixed list of claims and transformation rules, you can save configuration properties parsing and make the converter a little shorter.

Comment: Last, I am refreshing introduction tutorials and [this one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples%2Ftutorials%2Fservlet-resource-server) could be more explicit on which pieces of configuration you need.

Comment: Anyhow, you'll still have a significant quantity of Java configuration to write with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (authorities mapping, authentication converter, session management, csrf protection, access-control and probably CORS configuration), reason for me writing `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server` which controls all that from properties as demoed there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default